# Specifing content-type for non-JSON ajax

Tags: php, javascript, content-type

I recently added JSON content types to all server code that was returning JSON. i.e.  header('Content-Type: application/json');  I also have a lot of script which is expecting only true/false or 1/0.  I recognize I do not need to specify a content-type, however, am curious if it is best practice and I should do so.  Please advise.  Thank you

My Javascript for non-JSON ajax

```
$.post('file.php',obj,
function (status) {
  if(status==1) {alert('do this');}
  else{alert('do that');return false;}
});
```

file.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: ???/???');
echo(1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Thanks Claudrian.  Do you typically add the header for readability benefits, browser consistency, etc?

Comment: `text/plain` is the generic catch-all for text with no formatting/display rules. Your server should _always_ return a content type - that way the browser knows if it should download it, pass it to an extension or render it directly.

Comment: Headers instruct the browser what to do with the content. It cannot guess. Images are image/jpeg or image/png, text is text/plain, html is text/html ... and so on. These are MIME types and without them, the content a server sends to a browser would be just binary stuff (application/octet+stream).

Comment: Thanks Basic and Claudrian.  I had thought that my server automatically returns text/plain in nothing specified, but feel like it is a good idea to duplicate it in case I reconfigure my server, etc.